# setting up OpenID authentication using Zend_Auth_Adapter_OpenId

Tags: openid, zend-auth

how do i go abt setting up Zend_Auth_Adapter_OpenId ?

in the docs:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if ((isset($_POST['openid_action']) &&
     $_POST['openid_action'] == "login" &&
     !empty($_POST['openid_identifier'])) ||
    isset($_GET['openid_mode']) ||
    isset($_POST['openid_mode'])) {
    $result = $auth->authenticate(
        new Zend_Auth_Adapter_OpenId(@$_POST['openid_identifier']));
...
```

what do all the post do? i guess some is to specify which "part" of the authencation isit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to http://www.nabble.com/How-to-set-up-OpenID-authentication-to25571181.html there are some bugs with OpenID

> Unfortunately, Zend_Openid has a few
>   issues. I started doing some testing
>   last week and will roll in some fixes
>   in a while. In the meantime, I suggest
>   reverting to something like the
>   Janrain PHP library while this is
>   being fixed.